# Install more recent version of xgboost

Tags: r, devtools

I currently have xgboost package installed from cran, the latest version on there is 0.9.

[On Github, the latest version is 1.1](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/R-package).

Tried:

```
devtools::install_github("dmlc/xgboost")
Downloading GitHub repo dmlc/xgboost@master
Error: Failed to install 'xgboost' from GitHub:
  Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
```

I then found [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/394) discussion with someone else struggling to install xgboost. On that page is a reference to the zip file at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/archive/master.zip

So, I tried downloading the zip file and then manually uploading to my home directory (hosted rstudio in the browser). However, rstudio auto unzips on upload of a zip file  so I was unable to `devtools::install_local()`:

```
devtools::install_local("~/xgboost-master/")
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from local:
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.dcf(path) :
  cannot open compressed file '/home/rstudio-doug/xgboost-master/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In read.dcf(path) :
  cannot open compressed file '/home/rstudio-doug/xgboost-master/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

There is a directory there called xgboost-master.

I then tried to install from the url with the zipfile:

```
devtools::install_url("https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/archive/master.zip")
Downloading package from url: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/archive/master.zip
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
```

Similar message.

I also tried pacman:

```
pacman::p_install_gh("dmlc/xgboost")
Downloading GitHub repo dmlc/xgboost@master
Installation failed: NULL : Failed to install 'xgboost' from GitHub:
  Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)

The following packages were not able to be installed:
xgboost
Warning message:
In pacman::p_install_gh("dmlc/xgboost") :
  The following may have incorrect capitalization specification:

xgboost
```

How can I install xgboost 1.1?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux 2

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] curl_4.3            httr_1.4.1          devtools_2.3.0.9000 usethis_1.6.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Metrics_0.1.4       xfun_0.15           remotes_2.1.1       noctua_1.6.0.9000  
 [5] lattice_0.20-38     vctrs_0.3.1         testthat_2.3.2      htmltools_0.5.0    
 [9] yaml_2.2.1          utf8_1.1.4          rlang_0.4.6         pkgbuild_1.0.8.9000
[13] pillar_1.4.4        glue_1.4.1          withr_2.2.0         DBI_1.1.0          
[17] sessioninfo_1.1.1   paws_0.1.7          evaluate_0.14       memoise_1.1.0      
[21] knitr_1.29          callr_3.4.3         ps_1.3.3            fansi_0.4.1        
[25] Rcpp_1.0.4.6        readr_1.3.1         BiocManager_1.30.10 backports_1.1.8    
[29] desc_1.2.0          pkgload_1.1.0       fs_1.4.2            MLmetrics_1.1.1    
[33] hms_0.5.3           packrat_0.5.0       digest_0.6.25       stringi_1.4.6      
[37] processx_3.4.3      grid_3.6.0          rprojroot_1.3-2     cli_2.0.2          
[41] tools_3.6.0         magrittr_1.5        tibble_3.0.1        pacman_0.5.1       
[45] crayon_1.3.4        pkgconfig_2.0.3     zeallot_0.1.0       ellipsis_0.3.1     
[49] Matrix_1.2-18       data.table_1.12.8   prettyunits_1.1.1   assertthat_0.2.1   
[53] rmarkdown_2.1       rstudioapi_0.11     R6_2.4.1            compiler_3.6.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The github repo for xgboost keeps the R package code in a sub-directory, not the main directory like most R packages do. You'll see the `DESCRIPTION` is in there. Try

```
devtools::install_github("dmlc/xgboost", subdir="R-package")
```

Comment: I diddn't know the `subdir`option

Comment: Thank you for the info. Tried:
```devtools::install_github("dmlc/xgboost", subdir="R-package")
Error in .shlib_internal(args) : 
  C++14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined
Error: Failed to install 'xgboost' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/Rtmp5fMzFW/file3ae71463755c/xgboost_1.2.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status```

Comment: You seem to be using an older version of R (`3.6.0`) which didn't have the best support for C++14 features on windows. It would probably be a good idea to upgrade at least to R `4.0.0` (see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b14-and-later) (Don't forget to install an updated RTools as well)

Comment: I've held off updating to 4.0. Note this is linux not windows. Will try upgrading in the morning and will post here how I get on, cheers

Comment: Oh, it’s Linux. What compiler version are you running. Sounds like you just don’t have support for C++14 feathers in whatever you have set up to build packages. That can vary by Linux install. But at least it’s finding the right files now.

Comment: "What compiler version are you running." Not sure. Ids there a way I can find out?

Comment: Depending on how R was built, it might be in `CXX` entry in `/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf`. In mine it says `g++`. If yours is the same, you can check `g++ --version`

Comment: Here: `g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)`

Comment: I also tried adding some code to makevars file per https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1084. I'm far down the rabbit hole now, trying to add a more recent version of xgboost

Comment: That link looks specific to Mac so not sure that would help. Did you see @jared's answer? I didnt even notice `v1.1.1.1` is on CRAN. Just `install.packages("xgboost")` would be better than an `install_github` probably. But that may still result in compilation errors.

Comment: Wow. That actually worked! I swear I'm not going mad but earlier I tried that and still got 0.9. But right now I do indeed appear to be on 1.1. This is great! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The CRAN version looks to be ~up to date (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/index.html shows v1.1.1.1). Uninstalling xgboost and installing using `install.packages("xgboost")` should provide version 1.1.1.1.

Another alternative is the dev version from github (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#installing-the-development-version):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DR_LIB=ON
make -j$(nproc)
make install
```

Comment: I think it's because I'm on r 3.6

Comment: I use 3.6.1 and I have the CRAN version of xgboost (v1.1.1.1); what version do you get with `install.packages("xgboost")`?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled with just `install.packages("xgboost")` and am now on 1.1!

Answer (score 1):

This worked under Windows.
You can download the complete `xgboost` package from [Github xcboost root directory](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost).
You will get a `Zip` file containing among others a `R-Package` directory.
Extract this directory to a temporary folder, eg. `~/Temp/R-Package`and make again a `Zip` file out of it : `R-Package.Zip`

Run :

```
install.packages("~/Temp/R-package.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
packageVersion('xgboost')
[1] ‘1.0.0.2’
```

Comment: I was able to get the R-package dir zipped and tried: ```install.packages("~/Temp/R-package.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio-gavin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in install.packages : cannot install Windows binary packages on this platform```
I tried removing `type = "win.binary"` too which gave a failed non zero exit status message "Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\002\0\b\0V\037\xe6P\xa5\xf2O@-\0\0\03\0\0\0\021\0\0\0R-package/cleanupSV\xd4O\xca\x"

Comment: look at probably better answer from MrFlick

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to install xgboost R package and it's failing with following error on RHEL 7.

R version 3.6.3

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xgboost’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘xgboost.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xgboost’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpyH6aZ3/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("xgboost") :
  installation of package ‘xgboost’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment instead.